# MySQL function that returns the non null

Tags: mysql, function, null

I'm trying to write a MySQL function that returns the non-null value from two values ( a, b ) ..However, I get an error

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION GetNonNull(a,b) BEGIN
IF a = NULL THEN RETURN b; ELSE return a; ENDIF; END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'b) BEGIN
>           IF a = NULL THEN RETURN b; ELSE return a; ENDIF; END' at line 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Why would you do that, there is [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: You cannot compare `NULL` with any value (even `NULL`) using equals (`=`). How can something with unknown value (`NULL`) equal anything? Think of this: I'm holding something in my left fist, and something in the right. Are they equal? You can't tell, because  you have no idea what either of them are from where you're at; that's like comparing `NULL`. to something. Always use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` when trying to compare anything to `NULL`, and if you have an either/or use `COALESCE`, as @Darhazer suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the built-in [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function rather than writing your own function.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `RETURNS` clause which shows what datatype the function returns. And you have to specify the data types of the arguments as well. Check out [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$   
CREATE FUNCTION GetNonNull(a INT,b INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN  
    IF a IS NULL THEN
        RETURN b;
    ELSE
        return a;
    ENDIF;
END $$   
DELIMITER ;
```

or

```
DELIMITER $$   
CREATE FUNCTION GetNonNull(a INT,b INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN  
    IF ISNULL(a) THEN
        RETURN b;
    ELSE
        return a;
    ENDIF;
END $$   
DELIMITER ;
```

or

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE FUNCTION GetNonNull(a INT ,b INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
    RETURN IFNULL(a,b);
END $$  
DELIMITER ;
```

In fact, you could just replace the Stored Procedure with `IFNULL(a,b)`